# Starting problem, 2000 peugeot boxer 2.5tdi diesel engine

Tags: starter

My car was sitting outside for a few days. After a cold night It refuses to start.

Model: 2000 peugeot boxer 2.5tdi diesel engine

Battery: Brand new. Lights and other peripherals work fine.

Warning lights: None

I tried starting the car several times: The starter does the cranking sound at most 10 times and then it changes to the spinning sound until I turn the ignition off. Sometimes it doesn't crank at all, only spins.

What might be the cause and how to fix? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You could try and see if it needs more power (ie: using a jump box or getting a jump from a separate vehicle). While the battery may have charge, it may not have *enough* charge. If it doesn't, it might not be heating the glow plugs (hmmm ... not sure if your TDI has glow plugs, but would assume as much) all the way or fast enough to allow for ignition. Secondarily, it could also be the glow plugs themselves. If not working up to snuff, might not be allowing it to get started. If so, you might have had an issue with them for a while, but didn't exhibit any issue until it got colder.